# results of two propositions using python

Tags: python

This is my first practice using python and I need to find the values of two proposition of conjunction, dis-junction,exclusive or conditional statement , and bio-conditional of these propositions.
I'm really beginner and just need to know where I'm wrong to make the right result of these propositions. 
Thanks in advance!

```
def conjunction(i,j): # conjunction i,j
    result = i + j
    return result

def disjunction(i,j): # dis-junction i,j
    result = i || result = j
    return result

def exclusive(i,j): # exclusive i,j
    result = j
    return result

def conditional(i,j): # conditional i,j
    if i = 0
    result = j
    if j =0
    result = i;
    return result

def biconditional (i,j): # biconditional i,j
    result = i = j && j = i
    return result
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and the output you want?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Volatility actually, I don't have sample of that sorry!

Comment: @Volatility ATOzTOA has made a good sample to that, it is regarding to truth tables but by using python this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def conjunction(i,j): # conjunction i,j
    return (i and j)

def disjunction(i,j): # dis-junction i,j
    return (i or j)

def exclusive(i,j): # exclusive i,j
    return (i != j)

def conditional(i,j): # conditional i,j
    return j if i else True

def biconditional (i,j): # biconditional i,j
    return (i == j)

output = [[],[],[],[],[]]
titles = ["Conjunction", "Disjunction", "Exclusive", "Conditional", "Biconditional"]

for f1 in [True, False]:
    for f2 in [True, False]:
        output[0].append('{0:8s} | {1:8s} | {2:8s}'.format(str(f1), str(f2), str(conjunction(f1, f2))))
        output[1].append('{0:8s} | {1:8s} | {2:8s}'.format(str(f1), str(f2), str(disjunction(f1, f2))))
        output[2].append('{0:8s} | {1:8s} | {2:8s}'.format(str(f1), str(f2), str(exclusive(f1, f2))))
        output[3].append('{0:8s} | {1:8s} | {2:8s}'.format(str(f1), str(f2), str(conditional(f1, f2))))
        output[4].append('{0:8s} | {1:8s} | {2:8s}'.format(str(f1), str(f2), str(biconditional(f1, f2))))


for i in range(5):
    print "=" * 30
    print titles[i]
    print "-" * 30
    print "\n".join(output[i])
    print "-" * 30
```

**Output**

```
==============================
Conjunction
------------------------------
True     | True     | True    
True     | False    | False   
False    | True     | False   
False    | False    | False   
------------------------------
==============================
Disjunction
------------------------------
True     | True     | True    
True     | False    | True    
False    | True     | True    
False    | False    | False   
------------------------------
==============================
Exclusive
------------------------------
True     | True     | False   
True     | False    | True    
False    | True     | True    
False    | False    | False   
------------------------------
==============================
Conditional
------------------------------
True     | True     | True    
True     | False    | False   
False    | True     | True    
False    | False    | True    
------------------------------
==============================
Biconditional
------------------------------
True     | True     | True    
True     | False    | False   
False    | True     | False   
False    | False    | True    
------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank a lot for that, but I have questuion: what happens if we just put exclusive or conditional < I mean to delete one of them , and rearrange true and false printing like;

Comment: (true, true), ( true, false) ( false, true) ( false, false)

Comment: I mean is it possible to make order of the print functions like the truth table ??

Comment: Thanks a lot! just one thing should I do that for each function to make pretty printing?

Comment: @Todd Updated answer... njoy :)